# How to apply a weight variable for logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Here comes a probably very easy question about how to apply a weight variable in R.

I use the ANES 2013 Internet Recontact Survey dataset. Here I have the variable weight, which must be used in order to generalize to population.

My question is very simple: How do I apply the weight for logistic regression?

My best guess will be:

```
fit.gov.trust <-glm(gov.trust ~ party.contact:weight, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

But I am not sure at all.

Comment: `?glm` has a `weights` parameter

Comment: Useful link about [formula notation](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/FormulaNotation.pdf)

Comment: There is a `survey` package.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the R `survey` package by Thomas Lumley, specifically `svyglm {survey}`

The home page below provides a nice introduction:

http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/